# Connection refused for PostgreSQL, cannot restart from status active(exited)

Tags: database, postgresql, port, ubuntu-18.04

Thanks in advance for any help. This is my first time asking a question here so forgive any blunders.

**Details:**

- server running Ubuntu 18.04
- PostgreSQL 10

**My issue:**

I was running migrations for Django 2.1 and encountered this error, despite having run the same command without error for some time now.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have established that this is an issue with my PostgreSQL database, but despite my best efforts have hit an impasse.

Since it seems like an issue with the port, I checked:

```
$ ss -nlt
State     Recv-Q      Send-Q            Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port     
LISTEN    0           128               127.0.0.53%lo:53                   0.0.0.0:*        
LISTEN    0           128                     0.0.0.0:22                   0.0.0.0:*        
LISTEN    0           128                     0.0.0.0:443                  0.0.0.0:*        
LISTEN    0           128                   127.0.0.1:27017                0.0.0.0:*        
LISTEN    0           128                     0.0.0.0:80                   0.0.0.0:*        
LISTEN    0           128                        [::]:22                      [::]:*
```

What obviously stands out is this part -- `127.0.0.53%lo:53` -- but I have no idea how to fix it. It looks like this is what maybe should read instead 5432...

My pg_hba.conf file looks like this:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
h!
ost    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

My postgresql.conf file looks like this:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
```

Finally, I have checked my firewall and added port 5432.

```
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

---

**Some other potentially useful error messages:**

```
$ service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-10-11 08:34:35 UTC; 17min ago
  Process: 9046 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9046 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I have tried following instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830346/postgresql-server-doesnt-start/898532), with the following output:

```
$ sudo systemctl start postgresql@10-main
Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ sudo systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2018-10-11 08:42:52 UTC; 25s ago
  Process: 9093 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main start (co

Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 postgresql@10-main[9093]: 2018-10-11 08:42:52.396 UTC [9098
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 postgresql@10-main[9093]: 2018-10-11 08:42:52.396 UTC [9098
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 postgresql@10-main[9093]: 2018-10-11 08:42:52.396 UTC [9098
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 postgresql@10-main[9093]: 2018-10-11 08:42:52.396 UTC [9098
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 postgresql@10-main[9093]: 2018-10-11 08:42:52.398 UTC [9098
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 postgresql@10-main[9093]: pg_ctl: could not start server
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 postgresql@10-main[9093]: Examine the log output.
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 
Oct 11 08:42:52 billow-droplet-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue today.
In my case I forgot to set `listen_addresses = '*'`.

In `ss-nlt` I have port 5432 listened:

```
State       Recv-Q       Send-Q       Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0        128               127.0.0.53%lo:53           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      0        128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      0        128                 0.0.0.0:5432             0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      0        128                  [::]:22                   [::]:*
LISTEN      0        128                  [::]:5432                 [::]:*
LISTEN      0        128                   *:2377                   *:*
LISTEN      0        128                   *:7946                   *:*
```

So, in your case, postgresql is not listening 5432.
Dumb proposition: have you tried `sudo service postgresql restart`? :)

**EDIT**: question is more than month old, and you, probably, solve this issue. If yes, share, pls, your solution.